# Derivate a function defined by an integral, whose variable are the integration limits

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have to find the derivative of the following one-variable function and evalue it for $t=0$:

$$g(t)=\int_t^{t^2} \cos(tx)dx$$

In class, we saw a formula that says that a function such as

$$F(t)=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x,t)dx$$

has for a derivative

$$F'(t)=f(b(t),t) \cdot b'(t)-f(a(t),t) \cdot a'(t)+\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}dx$$

I succeeded applying the formula but the last term - the integral term - gives

$$ t\cos(t^3) - \cos(t^2)+\frac{\sin(t^3)-\sin(t^2)}{t^2}$$

The thing is I cannot evalue it for $t=0$ because of the division by $t^2$, though the answer to the question is $f'(0)=-1$. How do I get that result?

Comment: First, it should be $$F'(t) = f(b(t), t) b'(t) - f(a(t), t) a'(t) \dots$$ Secondly, use l'Hopitals rule for the fraction.

Comment: The term gives -2 with L'Hôpital, but then the whole gives 0 whereas I shoud obtain -1 (thanks, I've corrected this).

Comment: the whole answer is: $0-1+(-1)=-2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral term is equal to $\int_t^{t^2} -x \sin(tx) \, dx$ and it is well-defined at $t = 0$ and if you plug in $t = 0$, you get zero. Hence, there is no need to even bother finding the primitive of $-x \sin (tx)$ with respect to $x$, plugging in the boundary terms and applying l'Hopital.

Plugging in $t = 0$ in the first two terms, we indeed get $g'(0) = 0 - \cos(0) + 0 = -1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite surprising because the result should be the same wether we plug in the value at the very beginning or after the integration, shouldn't it?

Comment: The fact that you get an undefined expression at $t = 0$ when calculating the integral "naively" results from the fact you apply the substitution $u = \sin(tx)$ and this substitution is not valid to perform when $t = 0$. Since the integral expression is continuous as a function of $t$, you can do the calculation for $t \neq 0$ and then take the limit but you can't expect to be able to plug $t = 0$ in the resulting expression.